# MPDF: No table cell border

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I'm creating a PDF output file using mpdf. I'm trying to display a certain cell with no border, but the border is always present. How can I hide or remove it?

```html
<td style="border:none;">Content</td>
```

Comment: Try with: `<td style="border-style:none">Content</td>`

Comment: No, that didn't work.

Comment: Maybe it is surrounded by other cells..

Comment: Let me try it with the other cells.